# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, asp.net

Quiero insertar en una tabla de sql la fecha de hoy pero al momento de guardar me aparece este error  "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated", el cual me imagino que es una conversion pero no se como aplicarla en el insert into de sql

```
     DateTime tiempo = DateTime.Now;
      DateTime FechaLimite1 = tiempo.AddDays(2);
  string guardar = string.Format("insert into PrestamoHerra(NoEmpleado,Planta,FechaPrestamo,IdEstado,FechaLimite,Total,Autorizo ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}');SELECT @@IDENTITY AS id", empleado, planta, tiempo, idEstad, FechaLimite1, Total, cod);
                cone.EjecutarComando(guardar, "SQL");
```

Comment: Qué dato tiene FechaLimite1? Ok, el error lo marca porque el dato que estás pasando en FechaLimite1, al convertirlo en DateTime, se convierte en una fecha no válida. Por ejemplo, FechaLimite1 tiene '13/12/2018', ´(13 de diciembre del 2018), pero el motor de base de datos lo está interpretando como 12 del mes 13 del 2018

Comment: pues es la fecha de hoy mas 2 dias, pero para hacer la conversion que tendria que hacer?, no encuentro una solucion de porder convertirlo

Comment: Ok, necesitamos saber dos cosas: 1) cómo guarda las fechas sql? 2 ) cómo estás enviando la fecha?  Me refiero a exactamente cómo está formado FechaLimite1

Comment: para guardar use getdate() yDATEADD(), nad mas que ahora el mismo error sale al querer mostrar la tabla, jeje :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas SQL Server tiene funciones para trabajar con fechas, por ejemplo adddate:

```
select DATEADD(day,5, current_timestamp)
```

day es el intervalo que quieres sumar (en este caso días, pero podrías ussar month para meses, o year para años).
5 es la cantidad que quieres sumar (lo puse solo como ejemplo)
current_timestamp es la fecha que tiene el sistema.

No se si funcionará esta línea:

```
string guardar = string.Format("insert into PrestamoHerra(NoEmpleado,Planta,FechaPrestamo,IdEstado,FechaLimite,Total,Autorizo ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',dateadd(day,2,'{4}'),'{5}','{6}');SELECT @@IDENTITY AS id", empleado, planta, tiempo, idEstad, FechaLimite1, Total, cod)
```

O en su defecto, cambiar {4} por current_timestamp.

¡Saludos!

Comment: ¡Ah! Para usar la línea que te escribí, deberías borrar `DateTime FechaLimite1 = tiempo.AddDays(2);`, si la dejas, te sumaría 2 y después otros 2 a la fecha...

Comment: Esa función de fechas aplica en todos los gestores de SQL? Por qué el OP ni siquiera ha indicado cuál usa

Comment: de heco me funciono bien, nadamas que ahora me aparecio el mismo error, pero ahora al querer mostrar los campos, lo raro esque antes no me aparecia

Comment: El mismo error al mostrar la tabla... ¿cómo muestras la tabla? Tal vez esté sucediendo lo mismo, que el motor de base de datos esté devolviendo algo como '2019-01-29', pero tu aplicación espere que llegue '29/01/2019'.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es evidente que en la tabla PrestamoHerra, el campo "FechaLimite" es de tipo varchar, no date. Por lo tanto, la mejor opción es que edites la estructura de la tabla de manera acorde. Quiza con una query como esta:

```
ALTER TABLE PrestamoHerra
ALTER COLUMN FechaLimite DATE
```

Si eso no es posible, guarda un string con la fecha. Algo asi:

```
DateTime FechaLimite1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string guardar = string.Format("insert into PrestamoHerra(NoEmpleado,Planta,FechaPrestamo,IdEstado,FechaLimite,Total,Autorizo ) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}');SELECT @@IDENTITY AS id", empleado, planta, tiempo, idEstad, FechaLimite1, Total, cod);
```

Comment: de hecho los 2 campos son datetime por eso se me hacer raro, pero al momento de guardar lo cambie por getdate(), y el DATEADD y me lo acepto, ya no me marco el error, solo que cuando lo quiero mostrar en una tabla me muestra igual el mismo error